# Get TTL values for SRV records in Node

Tags: node.js, dns, srv

I'm trying to get the TTL of SRV records using node's [dns](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) library. It seems they return TTLs for almost all resolve* requests except [resolveSrv](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvesrv_hostname_callback). Am I missing something?

I'm building a service client that fails over to a lower priority address in the SRV record when a higher priority service fails. I need the TTL so that the client can know when to try the higher priority service again.